# Problem trying to install diesel (Mac air m1)

Tags: rust, rust-cargo, rust-diesel

I am following the diesel guide: [LINK](https://diesel.rs/guides/getting-started)

When I try this:

```
cargo install diesel_cli --no-default-features --features postgres
```

I receive this error:

```
error: failed to compile `diesel_cli v1.4.1`, intermediate artifacts can be found at
```

and a note:

```
 = note: ld: library not found for -lpq
```

Comment: This means that cargo cannot locate the `pq` library for linking, You just need to install it: `yum install libpq` for centos, shouldn't be too difficult to locate the needed package for your machine

Comment: Yes, sudo apt install libpq-dev but i cant... and i have java and path ok.

msg: he operation couldn’t be completed. Unable to locate a Java Runtime that supports apt.
Please visit http://www.java.com for information on installing Java.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Solution:

The problem is cargo cannot locate the pq library, so i need to use:

```
 sudo apt install libpq-dev
```

This send me a error too:

```
The operation couldn’t be completed. Unable to locate a Java Runtime that supports apt.
Please visit http://www.java.com for information on installing Java.
```

First
I need to check Environment Variables, check your file:

```
% open -e .bash_profile
```

File content:

```
export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)
```

But the error continue... so then that doesnt help me. I think sometimes just need this, in my case i install the elements by one bye with brew.

Second:
Install postgreql

```
brew install postgresql
```

Third:Install libpq

```
brew install libpq
```

Finally: Install diesel CLI

```
cargo install diesel_cli --no-default-features --features postgres
```

Answer (score 3):

I've just encountered this issue, and didn't find the various answers around to be especially helpful. The crux of the problem for me was that, whilst it was obvious I needed to have `libpq` installed, it was *not* obvious that installing PosgreSQL is also mandatory. Moreover, `brew install postgresql` no longer works; you must specify which version to install.

Additionally, I also wanted Sqlite support, and had found no examples of installing both PG and Sqlite support without MySQL support.

What finally worked for me:

```bash
brew install libpq postgresql@15
brew link postgresql@15
cargo install diesel_cli --no-default-features --features postgres,sqlite
```

Comment: This one solved it for me! Thank you! I executed the first 2 instructions and ran the `cargo install diesel ...`. I didn't need to do the export.

Answer (score 1):

Once you have install

```
brew install postgresql
brew install libpq
```

Install diesel CLI

```
arch -x86_64 cargo install diesel_cli --no-default-features --features postgres
```