# cannot link libpq on Mac M1

Tags: postgresql, macos, libpq, rust-diesel

I've been trying to run the Rust Diesel crate on my Macbook M1 and it doesn't work. The final part of the compilation gets broken by the following error:

```
  = note: ld: warning: ignoring file /usr/local/Cellar/libpq/14.1/lib/libpq.dylib, building for macOS-arm64 but attempting to link with file built for macOS-x86_64
          Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
```

When I get the info for `libpq` I get the following:

```
maxwellflitton@Maxwells-MacBook-Pro vanguard % brew info libpq                                                           
libpq: stable 14.1 (bottled) [keg-only]
Postgres C API library
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/libpq.html
/usr/local/Cellar/libpq/14.1 (2,335 files, 27.8MB)
  Poured from bottle on 2022-01-09 at 00:14:32
From: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/HEAD/Formula/libpq.rb
License: PostgreSQL
==> Dependencies
Required: krb5 ✔, openssl@1.1 ✔
==> Caveats
libpq is keg-only, which means it was not symlinked into /usr/local,
because conflicts with postgres formula.

If you need to have libpq first in your PATH, run:
  echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/libpq/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc

For compilers to find libpq you may need to set:
  export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/libpq/lib"
  export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/libpq/include"
```

I've tried installing with the following command:

```
RUSTFLAGS='-L /usr/local/Cellar/libpq/14.1/lib' cargo install diesel_cli --no-default-features --features postgres --force
```

But I still get the same error. Will it just be easier to wipe the whole thing and start again and if so how would I do this? Other people on the internet using the M1 seem to be able to get round the problem with a simple `brew install libpq`. Never had any issues with my previous intel mac. My `~/.cargo/config.toml` has the following configuration:

```
[target.aarch64-apple-darwin]
rustflags = '-L /usr/local/Cellar/libpq/14.1/lib -L /opt/homebrew/lib'
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Problem trying to install diesel (Mac air m1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70383711/problem-trying-to-install-diesel-mac-air-m1)

Comment: Hi Max, I am just reading your book right now, was funny seeing your name in this post. I have the same problem as you. Was this solved yet? When I try to install diesel I end up with this message: "ld: warning: ignoring file /usr/local/Cellar/libpq/14.5/lib/libpq.dylib, building for macOS-arm64 but attempting to link with file built for macOS-x86_64"

Comment: @Mactov hey sorry it's been a year, I ended up wiping my macbook completely and starting again and it seemed to have worked.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Surprisingly this worked

- `brew install postgresql libpq`
- `cargo clean`
- `cargo build`
- `cargo install diesel_cli --no-default-features --features postgres`

I think it had to do with installing `diesel-cli` before installing the necessary dependencies. Cleaning the cargo dependencies and reinstalling worked for me

Comment: Thank you the cargo clean was the missing step for me. Probably linked to a dead location

Answer (score 4):

Encountered a similar problem, and the issue was coming from my brew config  (I restored my filesystem from my mac Intel) :

```
❯ brew config
...
macOS: 12.6-x86_64
...
```

Therefore, brew was downloading packages built for intel processors. I uninstalled and reinstalled brew following [their website](https://brew.sh/) and now brew config is correct:

```
❯ brew config
...
macOS: 12.6-arm64
...
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

on my M1 mac, I installed the postgresql client and library with `brew`:

```
brew install postgresql libpq
```

and attempted to install `diesel_cli` again, this time it worked fine:

```
cargo install diesel_cli --no-default-features --features postgres
```

for some reason, simply installing `libpq` was not enough to install `diesel_cli`, i had to install the postgres library *and* the client.

Comment: I was able to build diesel but when I try to run it I still get an error

```
    Finished release [optimized] target(s) in 22.52s
   Replacing /Users/a/.cargo/bin/diesel
    Replaced package `diesel_cli v1.4.1` with `diesel_cli v1.4.1` (executable `diesel`)
➜   git:(master) ✗ diesel setup                                                            
dyld[72305]: symbol not found in flat namespace '_PQclear'
[2]    72305 abort      diesel setup
```

Answer (score 2):

I have a Mac M1 and installed both postgresql and libpq with brew

I eventually succeeded in installing diesel_cli with these lines in my ~/.cargo/config.toml file

```
[target.aarch64-apple-darwin]
rustflags = '-L /opt/homebrew/opt/libpq/lib -L /opt/homebrew/lib'
```

source was https://github.com/diesel-rs/diesel/issues/2605

Comment: This is what fixed the error for me when attempting to build Lemmy (`lemmy_server` crate) locally on a Mac M2 Max

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to compile a rust project I built. It's because of the target, its trying to compile for `arm64` however the dylib for postgres its using is for `x64_86`. So it throws this error.

I tried to reinstall `libpq` but still have the same error—might compile it for `x64_86` and run it through rosetta.

This is the exact error I have:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
            "_PQclear", referenced from:
```

```
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
          clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I ended up reinstalling `postgresql` and `libpq` with `arm64` variants while preserving `x64_86` for projects that aren't updated and need to use `x64_86` code:

https://codetinkering.com/switch-homebrew-arm-x86/

Answer (score 0):

I was getting `dyld[38508]: Symbol not found: _PQclear` on my intel macbook pro 2019, I managed to solve by updating my Dynamic Link library Path and adding postgresql's location (you can find by running which psql)

```
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH={PSQL path}:$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

my `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` is now `/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql@14/14.11_1/lib/postgresql@14/:/usr/local/bin/psql`

the second entry is for the psql path so dyld can find _PQclear (and probably helps with other postgres missing C symbols)

The first entry was because after fixing this, I also had an issue where diesel couldn't find libpq.5.dylib dyld[40597]: `Library not loaded: @rpath/libpq.5.dylib` so I added the path to my postgresql lib as well

now diesel works!